# How do I work out why scrapy deltafetch is still returning previously scraped items

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using windows and installed scrapy deltafetch and enabled it in my settings.py file

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'coal.middlewares.CoalSpiderMiddleware': 543,
    'scrapy_deltafetch.DeltaFetch': 100,
}
DELTAFETCH_ENABLED = True
```

Other settings I have are:

```
FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'
FEED_URI = 'coal.csv'
```

I execute my spider using the script below but the same items are being scraped after I run it multiple times.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(NqbpSpider)
    process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

How do I debug why deltafetch is not working?

Comment: don't you get any error messages? [Documentation](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-deltafetch) shows it need module `bsddb3`. And on Linux may need `libdb-dev`

Comment: no error messages, the data just get scraped each time i run the spider. I've installed bsddb3